# How converting & deconverting input[type=date] value to unixtime one line

Tags: php, html, date, datepicker, unix-timestamp

PHP Example

```
<?
prinr_r($_GET);

$after = // Convert $_GET['after'] to unixtime
$before = $after + 86400;
$before2 = // Convert to HTML5 date type ($before);

?>

<form action=''>
 <input type='date' name='time_after'>
 <input type='date' name='time_before' value='<?=$before2?>'>
 <input type='submit' value='send'>
</form>
```

How simple converting unixtime to HTML5 date or HTML5 to unixtime? One line)

P.S. Please help simply this:

```
$t1 = explode('-',$_GET['after']);
$t2 = explode('-',$_GET['before']);
if($t1[2]){
$t1 = mktime(0,0,0,(int)$t1[1],(int)$t1[2],$t1[0]);
}else{
  $t1 = mktime(0,0,0,date('n'),date('j'),date('Y'))-2592000;
}  
if($t2[2]){
  $t2 = mktime(23,59,59,(int)$t2[1],(int)$t2[2],$t2[0]);
}else{
  $t2 = mktime(23,59,59,date('n'),date('j'),date('Y'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-liner (php>=5.4) :

```
echo (new DateTime($_GET['after']))->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d');
```

or two-liner (php>=5.2) :

```
$dt = new DateTime($_GET['after']);
echo $dt->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

IIRC HTML5 provides the date in a "Y-m-d" format. That means we can simply do:

```
$after = strtotime($_GET['after']);
$before = $after + 86400;
$before2 = date("Y-m-d",$before);
```

The [date docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) provide plenty of info.